# Has anyone successfully setup a jQuery file uploader with safecracker?

Tags: safecracker, file-uploads, jquery, safecracker-file

Has anyone successfully setup a jQuery file uploader with safecracker?

I am looking to have a jQuery file uploader in a safecracker form for a new project I am about to start.

Any guidance, or experience in the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: When you say jQuery file uploader, are you trying to do this with AJAX? The Safecracker file upload field doesn't use jQuery (at least for the upload portion), so I am just wondering what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi Justin. I want to use something like  this: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/
I want to be able to have the file uploaded through a jQuery or HTML5 uploader that checks the size of the upload before it starts, and shows a progress bar. The idea is that I could have it within the safecracker form, just like the safecracker file field. When the image uploads, it attaches itself to the form.

Comment: Send me an email to support[at]objectivehtml.com. I have a new add-on that is being beta tested right now that uses that exact same library and works with Safecracker and Matrix. I have been developing this add-on since July of 2012 and will be a major commercial release (in a few weeks). I am 95% finished with the features, so if this is something that interests you, I can send a copy prior to the actual release. I think it will solve your problem perfectly (albeit not for free).

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to officially follow up with this thread. A couple weeks ago Photo Frame was released, which can be a replacement for Safecracker File among many other things. Photo Frame is a very robust add-on that allows users to upload, manage, edit, and crop photos right within ExpressionEngine and is compatible with many of the most popular add-ons. At the core it asynchronously uploads photos with a visible progress bar and clear interface. Photo Frame comes with 100's of features, and has additional expansion packs available for even more capabilities. Photo Frame is by far the most robust and advanced photo editor for ExpressionEngine, and developers will rejoice when using the API's for some serious customization.

Official Release

https://objectivehtml.com/articles/read/photo-frame-1.0

Overview

https://objectivehtml.com/photo-frame